# Can I deploy a war or java web application into Azure with git?

Tags: java, deployment, git, azure, jsp

I allways use control version to develop webs and apps. Now we will make an java web app and deploy it in Microsoft Azure and I've seen that you can upload content with git. But in the case of java webs, I think that you need to upload the war and I don't want to add the war to my control version as for my point of view it isn't a good idea.

For now I use the classic ftp approach.

**Is there a way to use git to publish a java web app into Azure without adding the war?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of this moment there is no way to compile a Java Application on App Service, thus you will need to deploy the `war` file to app service. You could create a separate repository in which you put binaries, so that you don't deploy your entire source code with the `war` file as it's not needed.

If you have any suggestions on how you would prefer to do git deployments with Java Application on App Service, please provide some [feedback](http://feedback.azure.com).